# What is the difference between component of displacement along force and component of force along displacement?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

I'm new to the chapter work. I have doubts regarding the component of displacement along force and component of force along displacement. Why it is necessary to take the component to derive the formula $$W=Fs \cos\theta$$ and $$W= F\cos\theta s$$

Comment: @wavion seeing $\cos\theta$ I would guess it is about scalar product, not cross product.

Comment: Sorry, meant dot product between F and s. My mistake.

Comment: This question seems to arise from an incomplete understanding of vector dot products. As such, it might be better suited to the Mathematics SE.

Answer (score 1):

Both are the dot product of the force and displacement vectors. Mathematically, there is no difference. They are just two equivalent ways of saying the same thing.